# Taking derivative of squared Frobenius norm

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have following expression:

$||Y- XW||_F^2$.

Where

$Y \in R^{n \times K}, X \in R^{n \times p}, W\in R^{p \times K}$

I would like to take the derivative of it w.r.t W and here is what I think it should be :
$-2X||Y-XW||_F$
I'm not sure whether this is the right derivation. Could you please check it ?

Comment: What is the Forbiouns norm? Are you thinking of the Frobenius norm?

Comment: Yes,  was tyop. sorry.

Comment: Yes, a tyop indeed!

Comment: looks like that something is going wrong with my keyboard

Answer (score 1):

As $\|A\|_F^2=\langle A,A\rangle_F$, $\langle A,B\rangle_F=tr(A^TB)$, you get that the directional derivative of your expression is
$$
2·tr((Y-XW)^TX\dot W)=\langle 2X^T(Y-XW),\dot W\rangle_F
$$
so that the gradient in the usual interpretation is $2X^T(Y-XW)$. That is, the directional derivative is the scalar product of gradient and  direction vector, and then the derivative the corresponding linear functional.